# All users receive 941 error message when trying to install my app from Google Play Store

Tags: android, google-play

I just published an app on Google Play.
Whenever someone tries to install the app he first receives the error message 941 and the app can't be downloaded. When trying again it is possible to install the app.

From what I found on the web this error message can be avoided by clearing the cache for the play store app. But since this is appearing on every device it seems to be a bug on Google Play store connected to my app?

I hope there is any way to solve this issue so the users don't get frustrated when trying to install the app

Comment: Yes, it is happening to me also but for only first time for every app I want to install... Second time it is installing my apps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've submitted a bug report for this error with the original log. The response I got from google play developer support was :

"As for the error 941 that your users are getting, you'll need to direct them to Google Play user Support for assistance with their devices. The error is not with your app, so there's nothing on my end that can be fixed.

You can give your users this link to contact user support directly: https://support.google.com/googleplay/#contact=1&ts=4626094,4626096"

You might well be sure that users don't only get frustrated but also dismiss your application all together. I had advertising campaigns before and after this error and conversion rates has dropped as much as 4 or 5 times.

Here is the part of log produced when user gets the 541 error.

```
08-18 23:47:03.692  5273  5311 I qtaguid : Failed write_ctrl(u 96) res=-1 errno=22
08-18 23:47:03.692  5273  5311 I qtaguid : Untagging socket 96 failed errno=-22
08-18 23:47:03.692  5273  5311 W NetworkManagementSocketTagger: untagSocket(96) failed    with errno -22
08-18 23:47:03.692  5273  5311 I System.out: Thread-301 calls detatch()
08-18 23:47:03.737  5273  5273 D Finsky  : [1] InstallerImpl.requestInstall: Request install of com.******** v=1 for single_install
08-18 23:47:03.747  5273  5273 D Finsky  : [1] InstallerImpl.kick: Installer kick com.******** - starting com.********
08-18 23:47:03.777  5273  5273 D Finsky  : [1] 4.run: Applying library update: account=[*************], corpus=3, numMutations=1
08-18 23:47:03.782  3041  3277 V SmartFaceService - 3rd party pause: onReceive [android.intent.action.ACTIVITY_STATE/com.android.vending/pause]
08-18 23:47:03.862  3672  5413 W GLSUser : GoogleAccountDataService.getToken()
08-18 23:47:03.992  3041  3277 V SmartFaceService - 3rd party pause: onReceive [android.intent.action.ACTIVITY_STATE/com.android.vending/resume]
08-18 23:47:04.017  3672  5415 W GLSUser : GoogleAccountDataService.getToken()
08-18 23:47:04.032  5273  5273 D Finsky  : [1] 3.onMutationsApplied: App library has changed, requesting content sync.
08-18 23:47:04.117  3041  3238 W LicenseLogService: log() is called by non admin
08-18 23:47:04.122  5273  5312 I qtaguid : Failed write_ctrl(u 96) res=-1 errno=22
08-18 23:47:04.122  5273  5312 I qtaguid : Untagging socket 96 failed errno=-22
08-18 23:47:04.122  5273  5312 W NetworkManagementSocketTagger: untagSocket(96) failed with errno -22
08-18 23:47:04.122  5273  5312 I System.out: Thread-302 calls detatch()
08-18 23:47:04.172  3672  3683 W GLSUser : GoogleAccountDataService.getToken()
08-18 23:47:04.252  5273  5311 I qtaguid : Failed write_ctrl(u 98) res=-1 errno=22
08-18 23:47:04.252  5273  5311 I qtaguid : Untagging socket 98 failed errno=-22
08-18 23:47:04.252  5273  5311 W NetworkManagementSocketTagger: untagSocket(98) failed with errno -22
08-18 23:47:04.252  5273  5311 I System.out: Thread-301 calls detatch()
08-18 23:47:04.262  5273  5273 D Finsky  : [1] 1.onResponse: Received non-OK response 3
08-18 23:47:04.267  5273  5273 D Finsky  : [1] InstallerTask.cancelCleanup: Cancel  running installation of com.********
```

Real relevant part of the log could be this line :

```
D Finsky  : [1] 3.onMutationsApplied: App library has changed, requesting content sync.
```